# Is there a single word for "becoming lucid"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Often when I want to say that something became clear, I may instead say that the thing "became lucid" or that the thing is "becoming lucid"

is there a single word that I can substitute for this?

Comment: *Bright, shining, luminous, resplendent*, are the four words used by the OED that cover its first considered meaning of *lucid*. Remember we are talking here of a 'thing' becoming *lucid*, not a person, or their thoughts. You have to get down to meaning 4 of the OED before you find that one.

Comment: Well, one could use "elucidate", but it would be a stretch in most contexts.

Comment: As an aside, I would find the phrases "became lucid" or "becoming lucid" a bit odd and obtuse. I would more likely hear the phrase "became clear" or "becoming clear".

Comment: How about some concrete examples of how you'd want to use the word you're looking for?

Comment: @ghoppe Exactly! I was actually looking for a more poetic way to say "become clear", but "become lucid" just sounded ostentatious to me. Lucid is like one of my favorite words though, so I was wondering if there was a better way to say it.

Comment: "I had a slow and gradual epiphany."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you refer to something that has been said or written, **elucidate** (tr vb) means "to make lucid especially by explanation or analysis." [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elucidate)

> - "When asked for details, he declined to elucidate further.

**Clarify** can also be used.  "to free of confusion" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clarify)

> - "Just a moment, let me try to clarify my thoughts"

Edit: "Only now has the truth been elucidated/become evident."

Comment: This is certainly a good partial answer(and may be the closest thing) but this only works with "make lucid" I couldn't say that "the truth elucidated" or, "only now did the truth elucidate" could I?

Comment: @LukeP You could say "Only now has the truth become evident/become clear/been elucidated.

Answer (score 2):

In less formal writing and in speech, I will use *clicks* or *clicked* as in "long division *clicked* once it was explained with examples." Thesaurus.com uses *click* as one of its distinctions for "become clear." This wouldn't necessarily work for "formal" writing though.

Comment: Elucidate: make (something) clear; explain - I don't think that fits the question. I can't find a single, "formal" word that fits. I think *Clicked* is it.

Answer (score 2):

You could say that it **dawned on** you.

> **dawn** *(v.)*
>
> Become evident to the mind;
> be perceived or understood:
>
> *the awful truth was beginning to dawn on him*
>
> (as adjective **dawning**) *he smiled with dawning recognition*

From [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dawn).

Answer (score 1):

**emerge**

From Mirriam-Webster:

> to become known or apparent

Example:

The facts *emerged* after a lengthy investigation.

Coincidentally, I *just* read the following newspaper headline after posting this answer:

> **Charles Manson wedding off after it emerges that fiancee Afton Elaine Burton 'just wanted his corpse for display'**

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not always usable, **unfold** has this metaphorical sense:

> *unfold*     verb ...
>
> 2 to gradually become clearer or more detailed
>
> *as the situation unfolded, it became clear that more help would be
>   needed*

[[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/unfold)]

Answer (score 0):

You could say you had an "epiphany"

epiph·a·ny
\i-ˈpi-fə-nē\
noun
. . . 
: a moment in which you suddenly see or understand something in a new or very clear way
(Free Dictionary)

Answer (score -1):

You can say you are ENLIGHTENED.

Comment: Please give a rationale for your answer.